# Javascript Uncaught type error: Cannot set property 'display' of undifined

Tags: javascript, html

Javascript cannot set the display property in my code because it doesn't think that it exists.

```
function toggle(el){
    alert(el);
    if (typeof el.display === "undefined"){
        el.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else if(el.style.display !== 'block'){
        el.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else{
        el.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
document.getElementsByClassName('menu-button')[0].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    toggle(document.getElementsByName('nav'));
    document.getElementById('menu-button').classList.toggle('ion-navicon-round');
    document.getElementById('menu-button').classList.toggle('ion-ios-close-outline');
});
```

Html

```
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css"rel="stylesheet"/
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="menu-button" class="menu-button ion-navicon-round"></div>
```

Comment: It seems as though either `el` or `el.style` are undefined. Also note that `undefined` doesn't mean `null`. It means the variable doesn't exist.

Comment: getElementsByName doesn't return an element - therefore what it DOES return doent' have a property `style` - that's the issue

Comment: Arrays don't have a property called `style`, and `getElementsByName()` returns an array, not an element.

Comment: @Archer - it's actually a NodeList not an Array as such

Comment: @JaromandaX It's extended from an array ;)

Comment: @Archer - absolutely incorrect

Comment: @Archer .. a NodeList has `.forEach` (in Firefox developer version at least) and `.length` ... what other Array methods/properties does it have? Please keep a civil tongue when you are proven wrong

Comment: problem with toggle(document.getElementsByName('nav'));

Answer (score 0):

According to your need please study on

### getElementsByTagName vs getElementsByName

toggle method expecting element but actually getting array of elements. make the call as

```
toggle(document.getElementsByTagName("nav")[0]);
```

refernce

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbytagname.asp

Comment: I know look at my own answer

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementsByName('nav')
```

Returns an array because their could be multiple occurrences of the 'nav' tag. Thus, we must define which tag we are looking at. In this case I would like to deal with the first occurrence of the 'nav' tag.

```
document.getElementByName('nav')[0];
```

Comment: "Returns an array" - close, but nope. It's an HtmlCollection.

Comment: Jan Dvorak have you tried using the second code block?

Comment: Except for the typo? That will work, but `document.getElementsByName("nav").forEach(...)`, for example, will not. The jquery object has a similar behavior. Look up "array-like"